# Why does my p tags inside of the td get styled according to the full table?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

My question is why do my `p` tags inside of the `td` get styled according to 
the full table?

What I want is for `top: 100%` to be 100% of the `td` height, not 100% of `table` height.

It is most likely some simple mistake on my part that I can't seem to notice 
so I would like if you guys could help me find that mistake or help me style 
my text based on the table data.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7oyxc1jh/

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> test </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <table id="buyingOptions">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p class="name"> PandaFeeder </p>
          <p class="productioning">Production: <span id="pandaFeederProduction"> 2 </span> </p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          2
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html,body {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}

table{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
  text-align: center;
}

td,tr{
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.name{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 4%;
}

.productioning{
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 4%;
}
```

Comment: `productioning`. That is my SO word of the week, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add:

```
td {
  position: relative;
}
```

to your styles definition. When positioning absolute, the browser must know relatively to what element the absolute element should be positioned. I this case you'd like the "td". Check the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7oyxc1jh/2/

Notice also that "top: 100%" means in this case - "on the bottom of the containing (relative) element, so it will appear in the second row in your case.

Comment: Thanks, just what i needed